# Encrypting data in SQL Server Azure database with separate key for each user's data

Tags: encryption, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to create a service based on an Azure SQL Database backend.

The service will be multi-tenant, and would contain highly sensitive information from multiple "clients" (potentially hundreds of thousands), that must be strictly isolated from one another and secured heavily against data leaks. "by design"

Using so many individual databases would not be feasible, as there will be a lot of clients with very little information per client.

I have looked into the transparent encryption offered by Azure, but this would essentially encrypt the whole database as one, so it would in other words not protect against leaks between clients or someone else; due to development errors, or hostile attacks, and it's very critical that one "client's" information never comes into anyone else's hands.

So what I would really like to achieve, is to encrypt each client's data in the database with a different key, so that you would have to obtain the key from each client (from their "physical" location) to de-crypt any data you might manage to extract from the database for that particular client, which would be virtually impossible for anyone to do.

Is it clear what I mean?

Do you guys have any suggestions for me on how to manage this problem, or know of any third party solution that allows for this functionality? Any other advise?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at protecting/isolating the tenants "by design" in a single table, why not check out [Row Level Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx). You could configure it to serve up only the applicable rows to a specific tenant.

This doesn't directly address your initial question about encrypting the data with a separate key for each tenant; If you have a separate table for each tenant, then you could do this via [Always Encrypted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163865.aspx), but this would seem to have some complexity in key management, if you're trying to handle 200k keys.

AFAIK, there isn't a native SQL Server functionality to encrypt each set of rows that belongs to a tenant with a distinct key- but there may be some elegant solutions that I haven't seen yet; Of course, you could do this on the app side and store it in SQL and there would be no issues; the trick would be the same as the AE based solution above- managing a large number of keys.