# Best way to store AES keys in .net C# while dealing with multi tenants (key per tenant)

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-web-api2, aes, multi-tenant

I have some valuable data in my DB that I would like to encrypt and only decrypt when I need to. Since i'm dealing with multi tenants, every database will have a different key (and IV). I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to store my AES key.

Another small question on the side, am I supposed to store the IV as well? Or I can generate a new one when I want to decrypt?

Comment: The IV has to be the same for decryption. DON'T RE-USE IV's!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, from the security standpoint and avoiding sensitive data in memory or in database I would like to suggest that you switch to Azure Key vault. These are more prominent ones that show up when you submit the code for security testing like with VeraCode. If this is a finding, the code change would be bit more and higher effort will be required.

In this case, you can have a secure vault configuration per tenant so that, the certificates are secure and no security keys are insecure at rest.

Moreover, we do not have more information on how you are managing your tenancy, as the above implementation will need to tweak the logic of handling your scenario.

In case you have a database per tenant,  the Azure default include Encryption at rest as per the following article. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/updates/newly-created-azure-sql-databases-encrypted-by-default/

Also, the link may be useful. [Encrypting data in SQL Server Azure database with separate key for each user's data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041208/encrypting-data-in-sql-server-azure-database-with-separate-key-for-each-users-d?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)